# Punctuating "What are you going to do, sue me?"

Tags: punctuation, commas, question-mark

For example:

> What are you going to do, sue me?

Is that correct? Or is there supposed to be a question mark after the first question:

> What are you going to do? Sue me?

It seems like "Sue me?" is not a complete sentence. Did I have it right the first time?

"What are you going to do sue me?" seems too abrupt though; shouldn't it have a comma?

Comment: The first two are correct. "Sue me?" can stand on its own. The last one isn't right.

Comment: It depends on the intonation.  If "What are you going to do" sounds like a question, I'd make it a separate sentence with its own question mark.  But the way I hear this question (in my head at least) I think it's usually better to use a dash.  I don't think a comma is ever the ideal answer, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Yes, 'Sue me?' is as valid as 'On the table.' or 'Fine, thank you.' or 'Hello there.'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A comma indicates a brief pause, or delineates subordinate or relative clauses within a sentence.

Speech tends to be more informal – you can certainly use a comma as per your example.

You could also use a dash like so:

> What are you going to do – sue me?

See http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/dash for more examples.

Comment: You can't really tell what punctuation is used here -- comma, semi-colon, question mark -- in speech. It's how that intonation is represented when written which is important.